# Screen resolution on Linux

Tags: linux, graphics-card, resolution, console

When Linux (kernel, e.g., 3.xx) boots, it starts to output messages on
screen in 80×25 VGA mode but then switches to a mode which is hard for me to
read. Unfortunately, from there on the system stays in the latter VGA
mode. This prevents me from working in mere VGA/console – as opposed to GUI –
mode.

Is it possible (e.g., by giving some kernel parameter) 
to make the display stay in 8×25 mode? The VGA parameters offered in
`lilo.conf` have no such effect and do not help.

<sup>Slackware 14.1 on Acer Aspire 2550 laptop</sup>

Comment: *"Is it possible (e.g., by giving some kernel parameter) ...?"* -- Yes.  For all the kernel parameters read [Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt).  For specifying the video mode study [Documentation/svga.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/svga.txt).

Comment: Still a problem? What do the uncommented lines in your lilo.conf look like?

Answer (score 0):

Check your lilo.conf file for an `append` line. If there isn't one, add the line `append="nomodeset"` to the end of lilo.conf. Otherwise add it to the end of the existing line.

Run `lilo` (or `sudo lilo` as appropriate) and reboot. This will affect your ability to run a GUI but if you're text only you should be fine.

Source: https://wiki.debian.org/KernelModesetting